# Itext 7.0.2 Clockwise rotation of Image

Tags: java, image, itext, itext7

Image element (com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image) supports anticlockwise rotation. 
Is it possible to make a clockwise rotation of the same image?

```
PdfPage page = iTextPdfDoc.getLastPage();
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), page.getResources(), iTextPdfDoc);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, iTextPdfDoc, page.getPageSize());
Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(path));
img.scaleAbsolute(525.58203, 737.0079)
img.setFixedPosition(30.785828, 34.66619)

// The following block of code does not affect the center point of rotation.
// I tried a lot of different values for rotation point. No change!
{
  img.setProperty(Property.ROTATION_POINT_X, 30.785828);
  img.setProperty(Property.ROTATION_POINT_Y, 34.66619);
}

img.setProperty(Property.ROTATION_ANGLE, Math.toRadians(90)); //img.setRotationAngle(Math.toRadians(90));
canvas.add(img);
```

**Update:**

This is what happens with the image using 90 degrees counter clockwise.
[image]

This is what happens with the image using -90 or 270 degrees counter clockwise.
[image]

Comment: How about `Math.toRadians(-90)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is due to:

```
img.scaleAbsolute(525.58203, 737.0079)
```

That line scales the image to be fitted into the container with

```
width = 525.58203 and height = 737.0079.
```

The following block of code makes what I need!

```
PdfPage page = iTextPdfDoc.getLastPage();
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), 
page.getResources(), iTextPdfDoc);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, iTextPdfDoc, page.getPageSize());
Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(path));

float width = img.getXObject().getWidth();
float widthContainer = 525.58203;
float heightContainer = 737.0079;
float horizontalScaling = widthContainer / width;

img.scaleAbsolute(widthContainer, heightContainer);

img.setProperty(Property.ROTATION_ANGLE, Math.toRadians(270));
img.setFixedPosition(imageLlx, imageLly + width * horizontalScaling);

canvas.add(img);
```

The result looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
img.setRotationAngle(Math.toRadians(270));
```

Why would you complicate things by creating two functions for something that can be done with only one function?

(The latter remark was influenced by the keynote by Venkat Subramaniam at the Great Indian Developer Summit this morning. The title of the keynote was: "Do Not Walk Away from Complexity, Run!")

**Update:**

After your initial comment (*I tried with 270 as well. For a reason I do not understand, the image has been rotated clockwise but it is positioned under the bottom of the pdf Page.*), I made this image:

[image]

In your second comment, you wrote: *You are right! That means that I have to set the position again so that the image to be displayed into the pdf page. How can I move the image, so that to be moved above the bottom of the page?*

That probably depends on how you are positioning the image in the first place. What are you currently using? Are you using the `setFixedPosition()` or the `setRelativePosition()` method? Or are you just adding the image to the document without defining a position?

Comment: I tried with 270 as well. For a reason I do not understand, the image has been rotated clockwise but it is positioned under the bottom of the pdf Page.

Comment: If the image is at the bottom of the page, then it makes sense that rotating the image 90 percent clockwise positions the image under the bottom of the page. Why do you think that's wrong?

Comment: You are right! That means that I have to set the position again so that the image to be displayed into the pdf page. How can I move the image, so that to be moved above the bottom of the page?

Comment: I am using setFixedPosition(). It should be something like setFixedPosition(x,y). x is the same like before. y should be the width of the image object.

Comment: Yes, if you create a PDF from scratch, the default y coordinate for the bottom of the page is 0, and the y axis points upwards.

Comment: It didn't work setting setFixedPosition(x,y) as I commented before. How can I find the rotation point of the image? If I change the rotation point then it might be that it will be rotated exactly how I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Set an image in page with different rotation and display the same result.

It is an example, you can accordingly set `x`, `y` .

itextpdf version 7.0.2

```java
    public Image imageWithPosition(int pageNum, PdfPage pdfPage, ImageData imageData) {
        val pageHeight = pdfPage.getPageSizeWithRotation().getHeight();
        val pageWidth = pdfPage.getPageSizeWithRotation().getWidth();
        Image image = new Image(imageData).scaleAbsolute(pageWidth, pageHeight);
        float x = 0f;
        float y = 0f;
        val rotation = pdfPage.getRotation();
        // rotation 180, 270 need to handle specially
        if (rotation == 180) {
            y = pageHeight;
        } else if (rotation == 270) {
            y = pageWidth;
        }
        // set fixed position
        image.setFixedPosition(pageNum, x, y);
        // toRadians 
        image.setRotationAngle(Math.toRadians(pdfPage.getRotation()));
        return image;
    }
```